# Hibernate Search @Facet not working with Lucene if index values have nulls

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

The @Facet annotation for hibernate search is not working for some reason. It is almost like it is completely ignoring that it is even there. I pasted the exception below but no matter how I configure it, it always fails...

I believe this is related to values being null. If a value in the index is null, it thinks that value isn't indexed. The value for upperModel above is null for this object in the database... I suspect that if we had values in each of the items I wish to facet on in the index, it would work. This is possibly a bug in the hibernate search when combined with Lucene 5.5.5 which is compatible by the Matrix.

`org.apache.lucene.facet.sortedset.SortedSetDocValuesFacetCounts getDim` returns null for the upperMake property if index contains no values at all... In my case, I only indexed one object for testing and it did not have a value for this facet...

I experimented by adding a value to all the fields I have set to Facet and no more exception. This proves the theory but I am afraid that if a user gets a result set that has all null for a single facet, it will error out searching...

The Code

```
@Facet
@Field(name = "upperModel", index = org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO)
@Column(length = 50)
@Size(max = 50)
public String getUpperModel() {
    return this.upperModel;
}
```

I also tried the following variants...

```
@Facet
private String upperModel;

@Facets({@Facet})
private String upperModel;
```

The Exception

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000268: Facet request 'upperModel' tries to facet on  field 'upperModel' which either does not exist or is not configured for faceting (via @Facet). Check your configuration.
    at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.QueryHits.updateStringFacets(QueryHits.java:407)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.QueryHits.updateFacets(QueryHits.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.QueryHits.updateTopDocs(QueryHits.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.QueryHits.<init>(QueryHits.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.LuceneHSQuery.getQueryHits(LuceneHSQuery.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.LuceneHSQuery.queryEntityInfos(LuceneHSQuery.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.doHibernateSearchList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.getResultList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:121)
    at com.jjkane.biz.services.SearchService.searchInventory(SearchService.java:846)
    at com.jjkane.biz.services.SearchService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c03b900c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
```

Comment: Interesting. Would you be willing to create a test case using our test case template https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-lucene ?

Comment: It's hard to reproduce but I can reproduce it consistently if I delete my index, then add a single item to the index with a null upperModel with every other value populated and then apply all the Facets to the query result... I get the error every time that way. I know the documentation says to avoid null values but this worked in the past. A simple fix for me is just to make sure that there is an empty string instead of a null in the upperModel value... I would assume that those steps could be reproduced in any index.

Comment: It's very probably a bug, I'll have a look: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2955